# JMS transaction with exception handling

Tags: transactions, jms

I am designing JMS application which receives the message from queue and updates the column in the database. I am using tomcat and message listener for listening of the messages (no MDB and no Spring MDP'S). I wanted the best possible, robust design in case exception handling and transaction so that messages are not lost.

Should i use jms session transaction mode and also jdbc transaction.
Or just the jdbc transaction is sufficient (without jms session commit or rollback) as this is an database table update.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A JDBC transaction is not enough: If you have read a message, and the database operation fails, and `tomcat` is shutdown, the message is lost.

---

If each message triggers an insert/update in a database, you could use `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` mode:

```
    final boolean transacted = false;
    final int ackMode = Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE;
    final QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(
            transacted, ackMode);
```

So you can read the message, and update the database. If the database update was successful, you can acknowledge the message using

```
    message.acknowledge();
```

Without `acknowledge`, the message will be redelivered: So after restarting `tomcat`, your message listener should see the message again. You can use `queueSession.recover()` to restart delivery programatically.

Since it is possible that `tomcat` is shutdown right between a successful DB update and the acknowledge, you should make sure to handle duplicate messages correctly.

---

A variation is to use a transacted session:

```
    final boolean transacted = true;
    // 2nd parameter is ignored if the session is transacted
    final QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(
            transacted, -1);
```

In this mode you can acknowledge multiple messages using a single commit:

```
        queueSession.commit();
```

You need this mode, if multiple messages result in a single database operation (you have to collect some messages, before you can update the database).